# Combining array with boolean elements with string in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array `arr` with some random numbers from 0 to 8847 and I wanted to convert it that e.g. if number is from 0 to 930, there should be 'a', if number is bigger than 930 but smaller than 3971, there should be 'b' etc.

My first idea was:

```
((arr <= 930) * 'a') + ((arr > 930 and arr <= 3971) * 'b')
+ ((arr > 3971 and arr <= 6053) * 'c') + ((arr > 6053) * 'd')
```

But this isn't working. So I thought that I can make something like this for every string:

```
a = ['a'] * 8847
a[arr]
```

It didn't work either.

I know that I can use loop and I know how to do it but I'd prefer to avoid that. Do you have some idea? This is my first day of learning Python so I'd prefer easily understood solutions.

Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bisect.

Look at the example provided here
[Example of bisect usage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples)